# Scratch numero binário invertido

Tags: lógica, scratch

O número binário está saindo invertido, alguém sabe como resolver o mesmo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para inverter a ordem dos bits, basta trocar o operador `adicione (0 ou 1) a lista` (que irá adicionar sempre no final da lista) dentro do bloco se/senão pelo operador `insira (0 ou 1) na posição 1 da lista` (que irá adicionar o bit calculado no início da lista).

O projeto fica desta forma:

[image: Imagem do programa em Scratch que converte de decimal para binário e mostra os bits na ordem correta]

Veja o projeto funcionando aqui: [Decimal para Binário 2](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/401839239/)

---

Explicando melhor, o bit calculado a cada iteração é o sempre o menos significante (LSB), portanto, ao adicioná-lo na lista, ela aparece "invertida" e, alterando a operação adicionar para inserir, os bits serão colocados na ordem "correta".

LSB (Wikipedia em inglês): [Least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit)